# Enable webp in php 7 without recompiling

Tags: php, gd, webp

Is it possible to enable gd webp support in PHP 7.4 on debian (with nginx) without recompiling php? All solutions I found recompile PHP7 with the `--with-webp-dir` param.

Comment: So why is that solution no good for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort of do it. Save an image file on your server, and then convert it to WebP.

See: [How to Enable WebP support Php 7 without Recompiling?](https://livtutor.com/enable-webp-support-php-7/)

I agree, it is not perfect, but quite close.